# Building widget in Flutter when response statusCode on API call is >400

Tags: rest, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

So I'm trying to call the REST API for the login here. This is in my api_services.dart where I am calling all the APIs for the application.

`api_services.dart`

```
Future<User> loginUser(String email, String password) 
async {
    final response = await http.post(serverOauthUrl+'/token',
    headers: {
    HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: "xxxx"
  },
  body: {
     "email":"$email",
     "password":"$password",
  }
);
print(response.statusCode);
final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
return new User.fromJson(responseJson);
}
```

And there are two ways I can call this `loginUser()` method in my UI files and get the response. One that uses the then() method and the other uses FutureBuilder. However, in none of the method, can I get the status code. My use case is that when the status code is >400, I will build a widget that shows the error message.

`login_screen.dart`

then() method code:

```
_callLoginAPI(String email, String password){
  loginUser(userName, password, "password").then((response) {
        response.data.token;
       // want my status code here as well along with response data
    }
    else
    {
      //todo show something on error
    }
  }, onError: (error) {
    debugPrint(error.toString());
  });


}
```

Or using FutureBuilder :

```
return new FutureBuilder<User>(

      future: loginUser(email, password),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print(snapshot.data.token);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return new Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        return new CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
if(response.statusCode > 400)
   return new Text("Error"):</code>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Thomas, this issue is resolved. Was an easy solution actually.

Adding the changes in the code for other beginners to follow :

`api_services.dart`

```
Future<http.Response> loginUser(String email, String password) async {
  final response = await http.post(serverOauthUrl+
    '/token',
    headers: {
    HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: "Basic xxx"
    },
    body: {
      "email":"$email",
      "password":"$password",
    }
  );

  return response;
}
```

So instead of the User, I'm returning the http.Response object and now I can retrieve all the required info from the UI files.

Like this:

```
final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      User user = User.fromJson(responseJson);
      print(user.userName);
```

Hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you return an Api Result object instead of a user that contains the error code and the user?
Then you can build different widgets on your FutureBuilder depending on the status code.